# How do I edit the label tags 'for' elements name

Tags: 8, forms

When I render my custom form in a twig there is a `<label>` above the element.

```
<label for="edit-children">CHILDREN</label>
<select id="ck_children" class="form-control form-select" data-drupal-selector="edit-children" name="children">
```

But as for the W3C standard, attribute `for` in the `<label>` should have the same value as the `<select>` tags `id`. But in this one `for` attribute has the value of `data-drupal-selector` s value. How to change the `for` attributes value to be equal as the `<select>` tags `id`.

Comment: You could just copy the select id over to the for attribute

Comment: I am not sure you can without changing what Drupal core does. There is probably a reason why Drupal core does that; changing it is probably going to have collateral, undesired, effects.

Comment: The select id looks altered.

Comment: @kiamlaluno But this will fail the W3C standard. How can I overcome it?

Comment: @Jdrupal unfortunately I can't do because this is generating automatically from the Drupal system.